# How to store/ retrieve data properly in firebase database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have users and todos. I want to see all todos from all users and then when I click on one todo I want to get the information from the user that created the todo. At the same time, I want to click on a user and see old todos of that particular user.

What is the right way of storing data?

I am currently doing like this to retrieve data:

```
     todos.id=222
        <Link to={'/todos/' + todos.id}>  

        todos:{
        222:{
        uid:123,
        done:false,
        task: buy milk,
        timestamp:2019-01-04
        }
        ,
    333:{
        uid:166,
        done:false,
        task: buy milk,
        timestamp:2019-01-04
        }
       }



   Users:{     
        123:{
        email:'@',
        username:'Foo',
        oldTodos:{
                   1:{
                      done:true,
                      timestamp:2019-01-01,
                      task: walk dog,
                     },
                   2:{
                      done:true,
                      timestamp:2019-01-03,
                      task: pet cat,
                     }
                  }
           }
     }



firebase
.database()
.ref('todos/' + 222)
.once('value')
.then(function(snapshot) {
    var uid = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().uid)|| '0'
//uid in this case is 123, and then i doo second call to get user data

    firebase
    .database()
    .ref('users/' + 123)
    .once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) {
     var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || '0'      
     })

 })
```

How ever this dos not feel right. 
What is the best practice?

Comment: The right way is the way that satisfies your queries.  So, if it works for you, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok, sou nothing wrong with nesting fetch?

Comment: Does it work the way you want?  If so, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you so much! that was all i needed to hear!

Answer (score 0):

You can get more efficient bandwidth by denormalizing your database:

For users:

```
users/{uid}/{
  email: ...,
  name: ...,
  username: ...,
  uid: ...,
}
```

For to do list:

```
user-todos/{uid}/{
  done: ...,
  task: ...,
  timestamp: ...,
}
```

For old to do list:

```
user-old-todos/{uid}/{
  done: ...,
  task: ...,
  timestamp: ...,
}
```

If you want to get all todos from all users:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref('user-todos')
  .once('value')
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    let allTodos = snapshot.val()
    // you will get uid and todo data

  })
```

If you want to get all todos from all users:

```
  firebase
  .database()
  .ref('user-todos')
  .once('value')
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    let allTodos = snapshot.val()
    // you will get uid and todo data
  })
```

If you want to get user data:

```
  // use uid from previous query
  firebase
  .database()
  .ref('users')
  .child(uid)
  .once('value')
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    let userData = snapshot.val()
    // you will get user data
  })
```

If you want to get old todos:

```
  // use uid from previous query
  firebase
  .database()
  .ref('user-old-todos')
  .child(uid)
  .once('value')
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    let oldTodos = snapshot.val()
    // you will get all old to do list
  })
```